# AWSIotMqttClient getConnectionStatus() doesn't show actual connection status

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have an application that is subscribed to some topics and publishes some events on the topic. Scheduler periodically checks the connection. Something like this:

```
AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(
        mqttBrokerAddress,
        clientId,
        keyStore,
        keyPassword
);  // it is a bean
```

Scheduler gets connection status, and if a connection is lost tries to reconnect:

```
var status = client.getConnectionStatus();
log.debug("Connection status is " + status.name());
if (status != AWSIotConnectionStatus.CONNECTED)
client.connect();
```

When I interrupt the connection I see that the scheduler logs connection status `CONNECTED` a long time after the connection is lost, and my application tries to publish messages. Only after 20 minutes, I see the `DISCONNECTED` status in logs and `MqttException` and `UnknownHostException`.

When I reconnect to the web I also see the `DISCONNECTED` status in logs, and my client couldn't connect to AWS. I thought that it is something with my internet provider when I close and reopen the connection. But when I stopped the application and internet connection and started it again together my application connected to AWS after starting immediately.

How do I get the actual connection status with `AWSIotMqttClient`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the `getConnectionStatus()` method gets a value of some `connection` variable set when the `connect` or `disconnect` methods are called. It doesn't verify the connection. So to verify the connection, I published a message on some topic, and if the connection is lost I receive an exception. And in catch block, I disconnect to set the correct value:

```
try {
    awsIotMqttClient.publish("connection", AWSIotQos.QOS1, "Check connection", 60000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("It seems connection lost. Disconnecting...");
    awsIotMqttClient.disconnect();
}
```